# UIButton custom backgroundColor in tvOS

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, swift2, tvos

I have a `UIButton` inside my `TVos` app where I want to change the `backgroundColor` and also the font of the titleLabel.

The text,font and `backgroundColor` should be the same when the button gets focused but it should be shown that it becomes a `focused view`.

I have these three lines of code inside my `ViewDidLoad`:

```
   orderButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "RobotoCondensed-Regular", size: 40)
   orderButton.setBackgroundImage(getImageWithColor(UIColor(rgba: "#1db5b5")), forState: [.Focused, .Normal])
   orderButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: [.Focused, .Normal])
```

**PROBLEM**

When my view is load, my button still has the default gray color. When it gets focused it gets the color that I've set inside my `ViewDidLoad`.

Any help on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you will have to specify both sates separately,like this

```
 orderButton.setBackgroundImage(getImageWithColor(UIColor(rgba: "#1db5b5")), forState: .Focused)
 orderButton.setBackgroundImage(getImageWithColor(UIColor(rgba: "#1db5b5")), forState: .Normal)
```

As Docs say

```
  func setBackgroundImage(_ image: UIImage?,forState state: UIControlState)
```

we have only one state at time to specify

Comment: It did the trick. But can't you do this in any way on one line?

Comment: As far doc say 
func setBackgroundImage(_ image: UIImage?,
               forState state: UIControlState)
we have only one state at time to specify,

Answer (score 0):

You can override the didUpdateFocusInContext method to achieve this.
Let us say that your button has tag set to 1. Now you can do something like this:

```
     override func didUpdateFocusInContext(context: UIFocusUpdateContext, withAnimationCoordinator coordinator: UIFocusAnimationCoordinator) {

        if let nextFocusedView = context.nextFocusedView {
          if button.tag == 1 {
       // Change the font and background color here for Focused state
            }
        }

    if let previousFocusView = context.previouslyFocusedView {
         if button.tag == 1 {
     // Change the font and background color here for Non-Focused state
         }
}
```